# Use variable value in Xpath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following XML

```
<root>
  <ns:Search xmlns:ns="http://example.com/1.0/">
    <ns:AllClass>
      <ns:class1>
        <ns:node1>fhgfjh</ns:node1>
        <ns:node2>Aprtyrtyril</ns:node2>
        <ns:node3>Juklyuiyly</ns:node3>
      </ns:class1>
      <ns:class2>
        <ns:node1>dfgd</ns:node1>
        <ns:node2>trytyu</ns:node2>
        <ns:node3>sgsdfg</ns:node3>
      </ns:class2>
      .
      .
      .
      .
      .
      .
    </ns:AllClass>
  </ns:Search>
  <ns:Req xmlns:ns="http://example.com/1.0/">
    <ns:classId>class1</ns:classId>
    <ns:othertag>asdfg</ns:othertag>
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
  </ns:Req>
</root>
```

and the following XSL

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:variable name="class" select="/root/Req/classId" />
    <ns1:Request xmlns:ns1="http://example.com/ns1">
      <ns1:node>
        <xsl:value-of xmlns:ns="http://example.com/1.0/" xmlns:ns1="http://abc.xyz.com/1.0/" select="/root/Search/AllClass[Value=$class]/node1" />
      </ns1:node>
    </ns1:Request>
  </xsl:template>
```

I am getting a class name inside my XML in 'classId' node. I want to get the value of 'node1' of the class same as my value inside the 'classId' tag. I am using a variable'class' and storing the value of classId and trying to get the value of 'node1' by using the variable inside Select Xpath. But it is not working. Please help.

Comment: did you try like this `/root/Search/AllClass/$class/node1`

Comment: Yes already tried that

Comment: I guess this will work `/root/Search/AllClass/data($class)/node1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use namespace in XPATH expressions:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:variable name="class_tmp" xmlns:ns="http://example.com/1.0/" select="/root/ns:Req/ns:classId" />
    <xsl:variable name="class" select="concat('ns:',$class_tmp)" />
    <xsl:message><xsl:value-of select="$class"/></xsl:message>
    <ns1:Request xmlns:ns1="http://example.com/ns1">
        <ns1:node>
            <xsl:value-of xmlns:ns="http://example.com/1.0/" xmlns:ns1="http://abc.xyz.com/1.0/" select="/root/ns:Search/ns:AllClass/*[name()=$class]/ns:node1" />
        </ns1:node>
    </ns1:Request>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Well when I am using static xpath without using the variable I am getting value

Comment: Thanks, I guess namespace was the reason it was not working