# I'd like to use element content from a variable as XPath value

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'd like to iterate through the elements in my var `trees` (stylesheet immediately below), using element content to provide different XPaths on each pass through the XML for processing (middle bottom). I think this would allow me to retrieve values from different XML structures using the same template.

This is admittedly a similar question to [Use variable value in Xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38393190/use-variable-value-in-xpath), but I'm not able to incorporate a namespace as seems indicated there in order to achieve my goal. Apologies if this is entirely due to a misreading of the Q/A there.

`val01` and `val02` contents in the output (far bottom) are *not* the desired element content and attribute values from the XML for processing, rather they are simply the content of `elementContent` and `attributeValue` in each `tree` element in my variable.

**Stylesheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet [...]>

    <xsl:variable name="trees">
        <tree>
            <elementContent>root/tree01/trunk/branch/leaf/text</elementContent>
            <attributeValue>root/tree01/trunk/branch/leaf/@attr</attributeValue>
        </tree>
        <tree>
            <elementContent>root/tree02/trunk02/branch</elementContent>
            <attributeValue>root/tree02/trunk01/@attr</attributeValue>
        </tree>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each select="$trees/tree">
                <text00>A tree here</text00>
                <text01>Element content: </text01>
                <val01>
                    <xsl:value-of select="elementContent"/>
                </val01>
                <text02>
                    <xsl:text>Attribute value: </xsl:text>
                </text02>
                <val02>
                    <xsl:value-of select="attributeValue"/>
                </val02>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML for processing**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <tree01>
        <trunk>
            <branch/>
            <branch>
                <leaf attr="elementAttribute01">
                    <text>Element content 01</text>
                </leaf>
            </branch>
        </trunk>
    </tree01>
    <tree02>
        <trunk01 attr="elementAttribute02"/>
        <trunk02>
            <branch>Element content 02</branch>
        </trunk02>
    </tree02>
</root>
```

**Output**

```
<root>
    <text00>A tree here</text00>
    <text01>Element content: </text01>
    <val01>root/tree01/trunk/branch/leaf/text</val01>
    <text02>Attribute value: </text02>
    <val02>root/tree01/trunk/branch/leaf/@attr</val02>
    <text00>A tree here</text00>
    <text01>Element content: </text01>
    <val01>root/tree02/trunk02/branch</val01>
    <text02>Attribute value: </text02>
    <val02>root/tree02/trunk01/@attr</val02>
</root>
```

Comment: Which version of XSLT, which XSLT processor do you use?

Comment: What is the purpose of this exercise? If you're going to hard-code the paths into your stylesheet, you might just as well hard-code them as paths instead of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 3 with support for `xsl:evaluate` (e.g. as in Altova XML Spy or Raptor, Saxon 10 all editions, Saxon JS 2, Saxon 9.8/9.9 commercial editions):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
  
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="trees">
        <tree>
            <elementContent>root/tree01/trunk/branch/leaf/text</elementContent>
            <attributeValue>root/tree01/trunk/branch/leaf/@attr</attributeValue>
        </tree>
        <tree>
            <elementContent>root/tree02/trunk02/branch</elementContent>
            <attributeValue>root/tree02/trunk01/@attr</attributeValue>
        </tree>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:variable name="main-root" select="."/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$trees/tree">
                <text00>A tree here</text00>
                <text01>Element content: </text01>
                <val01>
                    <xsl:evaluate xpath="elementContent" as="xs:string" context-item="$main-root"/>
                </val01>
                <text02>
                    <xsl:text>Attribute value: </xsl:text>
                </text02>
                <val02>
                    <xsl:evaluate xpath="attributeValue" as="xs:string" context-item="$main-root"/>
                </val02>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks very much Martin Honnen for this helpful response!